# How to replace all new lines of string with `<BR>` in php?

Tags: php, string, newline

There are too much confusion about \n and \r. 
There are lot's of questions in stack about differences between \n and \r. In a nut shell My confusions/questions are:

1. Is \r\n equal to \n\r?
2. Is \r\n cause to two new lines?
3. Is \r cause a new line in output?
4. How can I replace all new lines with `<BR>` tag in PHP?

**Not all strings has \r or \n explicitly**. Suppose I have a textarea and user inputs some characters including Enter of keyboard. No \r or \n is entered but new lines exist. **How to remove all new lines?**

Comment: 4. -> [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: thanks, How I forgot that function? I used it, but I'm sure it doesn't replace all new lines with <BR>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Microsoft Windows / MS-DOS: \r\n
>
> Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output: \n\r
>
> Apple Macintosh OS 9 and earlier: \r
>
> Unix (e.g., Linux), also Apple OS X and higher: \n

replace -> [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php)

more on that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

If new lines exists in the textarea than \n,\r or \r\n are present! These are control characters which are not outputted.

To remove them you could try:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n"), "", $string);
```