# changing new line to <br> in text area

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline

My problem is pretty simple. I want to change new lines in text area to `<br>` tags BUT I need the final string to be one-line text. I tried using `nl2br` function but as a result I get string with `<br>` tags and new lines. I also tried to simply replace &#013 or &#010 symbols with `<br>` using `str_replace` but it doesn't work.
Here is sample of my latest code:

```
Godziny otwarcia: <textarea name="open" rows="3" cols="20">'."$openh".'</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="openb" value="Zmień"/><br>
```

```
    if($_POST['openb']) {
    $open = $_POST['open'];
    str_replace('&#010', '<br>', $open);
    change_data(21, $open);
}
```

The `$openh` is result of this:

```
$tab = explode('<br>', $openh);
$openh = null;
for($i=0;$i<count($tab);$i++)
    $openh = $openh . $tab[$i] . '&#013';
```

(yes, I know i could use `str_replace`, don't ask why I did it this way)
and the original `$openh` is `$openh = 'Pon-pt 9:00-17:00<br>Środa 12:00-17:00'`

Also you may want to see my `change_data` function as it is connected to why i need the string to be in one line, so here it is:

```
function change_data($des_line, $data) {
    $file = 'config.php';
    $lines = file($file);
    $i=1;
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        $wiersz[$i] = $line;
        $i++;
    }
    $change = explode("'", $wiersz[$des_line]);
    $wiersz[$des_line] = $change[0] . "'" . $data . "'" . $change[2];
    $i = 1;
    $f = fopen($file, w);
    while($i <= count($wiersz)) {
        fwrite($f, $wiersz[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($f);
    header('location: index.php?p=admin');
}
```

I'm not PHP specialist so sometimes I do things little "hard" way.. I had huge problems with reading file `config.php` line by line and these are results of my few-hours effort :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

have you tried the php constant PHP_EOL? in you str_replace code?

```
$open=str_replace(PHP_EOL,"<br>",$_POST["open"]);
```

Comment: I didn't try it but I managed to do it with "\n" .. It just needed " instead of '
And all of this because my browser didn't load the whole page in PHP Manual last time.. Now I reopened page and there were some good examples of nl2br function and how does it work

Answer (score 4):

There is a ready made PHP function for that named [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16376133/469161